# How to build modules in parallel except for ones that depend on non-thread-safe plugins?

Tags: maven

I have a project that can be built safely in parallel, except for one or two sub-modules that depend on plugins that cannot be run concurrently (e.g. source code generators).

Is there a way to tell Maven to execute the build concurrently, except for these one or two sub-modules, and do so without getting the warning about the use of plugins that are not thread-safe?

Comment: Which plugins are they? If they are actively maintained, I would file a bug to make them thread safe.

Comment: @gjoranv I own the plugins. How can a plugin that generates sources be thread-safe? You can't write to the same file concurrently under Windows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Multi-threading in Maven parallelizes the build of modules. Within a single module, everything is still done sequentially. (Individual plugins may have features for further parallelization, [notably Surefire](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html).) Since your plugins presumably are only generating sources for a single module at a time, they could very possibly be thread-safe. An example of not being thread safe is if your plugin keeps state of the currently-built module in `static` ("global") variables, in which case parallel execution of separate modules would clobber these variables.